# NoSuchAlgorithmException : TLSv1.2 unknown protocol

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I have tried a number of things and searched a quite few posts but cannot found a proper answer to the below problem.

While making a ssl context i.e

```
ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

i am getting an exception as

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Unknown protocol: TLSv1.2
```

I tried to use another protocol that is

```
ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
```

but then i get an error as

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: algorithm not supported for certificate
```

please help me as to where i am getting thing wrong.

Comment: Which JRE version do you use? Only JDK 7+ supports TLS 1.2 initially. JDK 6 supports it from Update 121. And I don't think that JDK 5 supports it at all. I'm talking about Oracle JDKs, not sure about other implementations

Comment: yeah you are right .. i am using java 1.4 .. is there any way i can still use TLS in java 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using some ancient version of Java that doesn't support TLS 1.2.

Upgrade.

Comment: yes i am using java 1.4 but when i do ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1"); it creates a context ..though SSLHandshake exception is there which says algorithm not supported for certificate

Comment: Then you either have to switch to a newer Java version or you have to create/get new certificates which support TLSv1